# Keeping static files in server when deploying with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, release-management

I'm uploading files to my `public/files` folder of a Rails application on a constant basis through a web interface.

I don't want to keep these in source control since they go for almost 2 GBs, so every time I do a `cap deploy` it will save those files away in `releases/` and replace the directory with the pristine copy stored in the repository.

I'm wondering what's the best way to keep those files in the server, in the `current` directory. Some of my ideas are:

- Remove the directory from source control and replace it with a link to an external directory that's not managed by Capistrano.
- Create a Capistrano task to copy the directory to /tmp before deploying and then copying it back to /public after it's done deploying.

Is there standard way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make files a symlink to another directory on your machine, for examples the /shared directory at the same level as /current and /releases.

Check out capistrano manages the /log and /tmp directories.

Answer (score 7):

For the future record, this is the task I used to do it with a shared directory:

```
task :link_shared_directories do     
  run "ln -s #{shared_path}/files #{release_path}/public/files"   
end    

after "deploy:update_code", :link_shared_directories
```

Answer (score 2):

Now we can simply use :linked_files in deploy.rb:

```
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
```

In this case, the file [target_dir]/shared/config/database.yml must exist on the server.